# Laravel multi tenant can't create new databases

Tags: mysql, laravel, multi-tenant

I'm using this package[https://tenancyforlaravel.com/] to make multi-tenancy possible, each time I create new tenant I got new database, working great locally

But when I moved to live server/Cpanel i get

`` SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' to database 'tenantnew' (SQL: CREATE DATABASE `tenantnew` CHARACTER SET `utf8mb4` COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`) ``

how to solve this issue? how to create a new database that easily ? seems like I don't have permission even though I suppose to have it? I tried to use the Cpanel user itself and still didn't work

Comment: https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/customizing-databases  this package sets the db credentials in a table of the Tenant model.   do you have it set up properly? @samuelstancl may be able to help

Comment: @Cameron yes, and it's working locally , but on server it seems like the user i use to access db don't have permission to create databases

Comment: does the user test have access to create databases on your server?

Comment: @Cameron yes, he can create databases on server

Comment: did you add the user ``test`` to the db ``tenantnew`` with permission?

Comment: @OMiShah i try to create the db `tenantnew` using laravel, but i get the previous error, the db itself is not created

Answer (score 0):

This comes from privelages in database. I have exaclty the same error in docker and I solve it like this:

1. Login as Root user mysql -u root -p
2. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sail'@'%';
3. FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

- For Sail you must exec docker compose to give not through sail mysql because it logins through "Sail" user.

** If don't use the "user" of access. If you are not in sail and you use it on docker you can put it on ENTRYPOINT sh in order not doing it every time you build or you destroy volumes.